# Capture filter clear click event in jQueryMobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

How can I capture the event of clicking in the filter clear button for a listview component in jQueryMobile?

I have tried selectors `$('.ui-input-clear')`, `$('.ui-input-search a')`, `$('.ui-input-search :not(input)')`,... but I can not find the solution.

In jsfiddle works right, but I am developing for iOS and Android platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is old, but it comes up on the Googles so:

Instead of registering a click event, try registering a tap event.

```
$('.ui-input-clear').live('tap', function () {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: Absolutely right. I could not find the solution. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-input-clear', function () {
//code here 
});
```

Response for new features of Jquery and Jquery mobile